# Why do my pdb breakpoints disappear when the debugger goes to another file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdb

I think I figured how this is happening but I just want to know why it's happening.

I accidentally found that every time I call pdb.set_trace(), it seems to erase all the breakpoints that I've set.  I was just wondering why that is.  I couldn't find any explanation on Google.  I had set several breakpoints but midway through debugging I noticed they had all disappeared.  It wasn't until I ran a simple script with 2 pdb.set_trace() statements did I notice that if I ran pdb.set_trace(), breakpoints seemed to get deleted.  Hopefully someone has an explanation for me.

Example pseudocode:

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
print (a)
print (b)
print (c)
print (d)
pdb.set_trace()
print (e)
print (f)
```

1. At  print (a), I set a break point for line print (c) and line
   (print f).
2. I hit 'b' so that it shows my breakpoints (both of which
   are there)
3. I hit 'c' for it to continue, which it does until print
   (c), where it stops.  I check again and the 2 breakpoints are still
   there I hit 'c' and it proceeds until it reaches the second
   pdb.set_trace().
4. At this point when I check again, I have 0
   breakpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around some more with this, it seems like every time I execute pdb.set_trace() in my script, it will reset the breakpoints in the script, which is why they disappear like this.  If I just have 1 pdb.set_trace() line in my script, the breakpoints appear to stick until the end of the execution of the script so I will be more mindful and not put multiple pdb.set_trace() statements in my script when debugging.